# Cataloging a .tar file in AWS Glue from an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a file, "v1.02_train.tar" (from the Lyft dataset https://level5.lyft.com/dataset/), in an AWS S3 bucket. I am trying to add it to the AWS Glue data catalog.

How to do make a AWS Glue crawler detect the schema from a .tar file? I am hesitant to unzip the file because then the crawlers will catalog each image file individually adding millions of tables into the data catalog. Additionally, it will increase the size S3 bucket making the storage more expensive.

Any ideas of how to best catalog this collect of files?